# What file did esriControls.ControlsOpenDocCommand open?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.4

I'm working on a Windows application, using ESRI's ArcObjects.

In the ArcGIS 10.4 Engine ToolbarControl, I'm placing a esriControls.ControlsOpenDocCommand. With this, the user can select any .mxd file in his local filesystem.

I would like to save the path to this file, so I can restore it, should the user exit the application and the restart.

Does anyone know how I can determine this?

Comment: Is the user using some-sort of file dialog to browse for the .mxd file and select it that calls the esriControls.ControlsOpenDocCommand?

Comment: The user is using the esriControls.ControlsOpenDocCommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the control, trying to figure out how to hook into it's event stream, somehow, and not having any luck.

What I was missing was that the ArcGIS 10.4 Engine MapControl has an OnMapReplaced event that fires when the map is changed, for whatever reason. Catching this is trivial.